# Delphi Intraweb: Is there a way to open an url in a new tab without the popup behavior?

Tags: delphi, mobile-browser, new-window, intraweb

In an Intraweb (VCL for the web) mobile web application I need to redirect the user to a java webapp. I specify that is a java webapp to stress the fact that it is a completely different thing compared to the intraweb webapp.

I would like to achieve the following behaviour:

1. the user clicks on a button
2. the java app opens in the browser and uses it, **in particular he uses the mobile keboard to type data**
3. **the user taps the phone back button**
4. the intraweb application opens in the browser

In Intraweb as far as I know there are two ways to redirect the user:

Method 1) with `WebApplication.GoToUrl(javaAppUrl)`
in this way the history is lost so when the user taps on back he is not able to go back to the intraweb application

Method 2) with `WebApplication.NewWindow(javaAppUrl)`
in this way all seems to work in particular the back button works, but when I try to use the mobile keyboard to type something in the java app the keyboard appears for a moment and then it immediately disappears, I guess this is because somehow NewWindow "Creates a new popup window when executed in the browser context".

`NewWindow` has also some override methods with different parameters list but no one allows to remove the "popup behavior".

Could you please suggest a way to achieve opening a new webapp in a mobile browser:

1. keeping the browser history
2. being able to use the mobile keyboard in the just opened app
   ?

I use Delphi 10 Seattle, Intraweb 14.2.7 and cgdevtools for the mobile part (cgdevtools anyway plays no role in this issue).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a workaround by passing in the URL the webapp URL so that in the java URL I display a button that closes the session and redirects the user to the intrawebapp

```
javaAppUrl:= javaAppUrl + '&BACK_URL=' + WebApplication.FullApplicationURL(WebApplication.Request);
WebApplication.GoToUrl(javaAppUrl);
```

in this way I have the benefit of GoToUrl (so mobile keyboard works) and  I manage to have a back feature with a  custom button.

By the way this is still a workaround, I need this since I must release the application, but it is not the perfect solution yet.